# Saliency Model - BMS (having error setting up)

Tags: linux, matlab, opencv

I have downloaded a saliency model called BMS "Exploiting Surroundedness for Saliency Detection: A Boolean Map Approach" from [here - available online](http://cs-people.bu.edu/jmzhang/BMS/BMS.html). The code has been implemented and tested on Windows.

I am trying to set up on my machine (Linux Mint), by reading the instructions given inside the package in the file *"readme.txt"*. The file says that:

> 1. Put the extracted files in a .
> 2. Install OpenCV 2.40+.
> 3. Go to **/mex/** and specify the relevant OpenCV paths at the 
>      begining of the **compile.m**.
> 4. Run **compile.m** in Matlab.
> 5. Go to  and run **demo.m** in Matlab.

I have set up the paths of OpenCV in *compile.m* file as:

```
opts.opencv_include_path    =   '-I/usr/local/include/opencv2/ -I/usr/local/include/'; % OpenCV include path
opts.opencv_lib_path        =   '/usr/lib/libopencv*'; % OpenCV lib path
```

But, this gives me the error:

```
Error using compile>pkg_config (line 74)
OpenCV include path not found: -I/usr/local/include/opencv2/ -I/usr/local/include/

Error in compile (line 34)
[cv_cflags,cv_libs] = pkg_config(opts);
```

I have checked the paths to OpenCV package, all is good, but in MATLAB, the *compile.m* is unable to detect the files. I have tried all the options available online, but nothing works.

Please help me run the code, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that OpenCV lib is missing in your system.  You can install it in 9 steps:

1. `sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake pkg-config libjpeg8-dev libtiff5-dev libjasper-dev libpng12-dev libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev libv4l-dev libxvidcore-dev libx264-dev libgtk-3-dev libatlas-base-dev gfortran`
2. `wget https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/3.4.1.zip`
3. `unzip opencv-3.4.1.zip`
4. `cd opencv-3.4.1/`
5. `wget https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/archive/3.4.1.zip`
6. `unzip 3.4.1.zip`
7. `mkdir -p build && cd build`
8. `cmake -D WITH_TBB=OFF -D WITH_OPENMP=ON -D WITH_IPP=ON -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF -D WITH_NVCUVID=OFF -D WITH_CUDA=OFF -D BUILD_DOCS=OFF -D BUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF -D BUILD_TESTS=OFF -D WITH_CSTRIPES=ON -D WITH_OPENCL=ON -D WITH_MATLAB=ON -D WITH_LAPACK=ON -D WITH_PNG=ON -D WITH_FFMPEG=ON -D BUILD_opencv_python2=ON -D BUILD_opencv_python3=ON -D BUILD_opencv_python_bindings_generator=ON -D PYTHON2_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python2.7 -D PYTHON2_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/python2.7 -D PYTHON2_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so -D PYTHON2_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -D PYTHON2_PACKAGES_PATH=lib/python2.7/dist-packages -D PYTHON3_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3 -D PYTHON3_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/python3.5m -D PYTHON3_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so -D PYTHON3_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS=/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/include PYTHON3_PACKAGES_PATH=lib/python3.5/dist-packages -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/  -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../opencv_contrib-3.4.1/modules ..`
9. `make -j 8`
10. `sudo make install`

After installing OpenCV, you can compile BMS. In Matlab, set the variables   `opts.opencv_include_path=/usr/local/include/opencv2/` and `opts.opencv_lib_path=/usr/local/lib/`.

WARNING: test if the commands above are enough for compiling in your machine. The following commands might not be necessary.
I had some issues here (probably because I used Octave instead of Matlab). The issues were:

- In file included from mexBMS.cpp:29:0:
  BMS.h:44:2: error: ‘vector’ does not name a type

You can solve this issue by adding the following statement in line 32 of BMS.h: `using namespace std;`

- MxArray.cpp:484:55: error: invalid conversion from ‘const value_type* {aka const int*}’ to ‘mwIndex* {aka int*}’ [-fpermissive]

Add the following statements at line 484 of `MxArray.cpp`:

`int* pointer;
*pointer = si[0];`

- g++: error: BMS.obj: No such file or directory

Replace `BMS.obj MxArray.obj` by `BMS.o MxArray.o` at line 52 of `compile.m.

Comment: I have tried these commands, now, ´compile.m´ is giving this error in octave:

mex -I'/usr/local/include/opencv2/' -L'/usr/local/lib/'  -l -c MxArray.cpp BMS.cpp
warning: mkoctfile exited with failure status
warning: called from
    mkoctfile at line 171 column 5
    mex at line 29 column 18
    compile at line 48 column 18
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/octave/4.0.0
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mex -I'/usr/local/include/opencv2/' -L'/usr/local/lib/'  -l mexBMS.cpp BMS.o MxArray.o
warning: mkoctfile exited with failure status